# Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь сам вводил нужное количество input в js

Tags: javascript, массивы, input

Есть вот такой код, нашёл его на этом сайте, он выводит массив из input на страницу:

```
function srt() {
  var d = document,
    inp = d.getElementsByClassName('field'),
    mas = [];

  function save() {
    for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
      mas[i] = inp[i].value;
    }
    console.log(mas);
  }
  save();
}srt();
```

Но я хочу, чтобы пользователь сам мог вводить нужное ему количество выводящихся input, а не записывал отдельно в html каждый input, как в этом коде:

```
<input type="text" class="field" value="a" />
<input type="text" class="field" value="b" />
<input type="text" class="field" value="c" />
```

Уже перепробовал много методов и пока не получилось найти ответ самому(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// функция генерации инпута
const makeInput = () => {
  const el = document.createElement('input');
  el.type = 'text';
  el.className = 'my-class';
  return el;
};

// функция генерации массива элементов из необходимого количества. Такая запись позволяет использовать разные функции-конструкторы.
const generateElementsList = (count, constructor) => {
  return Array(count).fill().map(constructor);
};

// создаем элементы
const inputs = generateElementsList(10, makeInput);
// добавляем на страницу
document.body.append(...inputs);
```

Comment: А как к каждому input добавить класс, чтобы можно стилизовать его?

Comment: el.className = 'my-class' в конструкторе. Обновил решение, смотрите там

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы мне очень помогли